# Where query Json (Array) column in laravel

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, laravel, eloquent

I wanna do following code snap:

```
DB::table('tests')->whereIn('words', ['school','running'])->get();
```

using postgresql and 'words's type is jsonb
In words table data, like following.

```
['someword','someword2', .... , 'somewordn']
```

In raw query, I can do like following.

```
SELECT * FROM tests WHERE words ?| array['school','running];
```

I wanna do this using laravel Eloquent.

Comment: Can you provide exact issue that you have !

Comment: I edited my question, @Kuncham Vasu!

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent doesn't support jsonb in queries. The best way to go around this issue would be to use `whereRaw()` method. But, this method uses `PDO` for which `?` is a restricted character representing the argument.

Luckily every operator is just a shortcut to a function, which you can check listed here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/6498 which means that `?|` is the same as `jsonb_exists_any()`, and this is something you can use in your query.

Haven't tested it, but something like this should work:

```
DB::table('tests')->whereRaw("jsonb_exists_any(words, ['school','running'])")->get();
```